# Can we retract flags?

Tags: feature-request, flags

I think we should be able to retract NAA and VLQ flags. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/27035321/revisions) makes a good case for that: the original post should've been a comment (when I raised the NAA flag), but it was later edited to be a real answer. Since I raised the flag, I think I should be able to retract it the same way I can a close vote.

1. It can help shorten the queues
2. It helps users maintain a good flagging record

Like retracting a close vote, or after raising a NAA or VLQ flag now, a user could not raise the same type of flag again for the same post -- only spam, offensive, and custom-reason flags would be permitted.

EDIT:

I've also had cases where I'd like to retract a custom-reason flag. This may be even more valuable queue-shortening-wise.

Comment: Should this be a feature-request?